# SQL - How to calculate percentage change/growth

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with data in my database as follows:

```
year    month   sales   mom       qoq   yoy
----------------
2010    1   80  -     - -
2010    2   61  -23.75%   - -
2010    3   81  32.79%    - -
2010    4   94  16.05%      -
2010    5   77  -18.09%     -
2010    6   75  -2.60%      -
2010    7   58  -22.67%     -
2010    8   74  27.59%      -
2010    9   98  32.43%      -
2010    10  97  -1.02%      -
2010    11  94  -3.09%      -
2010    12  63  -32.98%     -
2011    1   61  -3.17%      -23.75%
2011    2   79  29.51%      29.51%
2011    3   84  6.33%       3.70%
2011    4   100 19.05%      6.38%
2011    5   78  -22.00%     1.30%
2011    6   99  26.92%      32.00%
2011    7   78  -21.21%     34.48%
2011    8   63  -19.23%     -14.86%
2011    9   66  4.76%       -32.65%
2011    10  77  16.67%      -20.62%
2011    11  93  20.78%      -1.06%
2011    12  94  1.08%       49.21%
```

I want to calculate monthly, quarterly and yearly sales percentage change for each month period (each row), **as shown in last 3 columns above**. 
How can i achieve this in one result set using T-SQL? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. Thanks.

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: Rolling yearly, or year-to-date? ditto quarterly?

Comment: please show what the output should look like and perhaps expalin why.

Comment: Following your edit, you now have 6 column headings and 5 columns of data. Where is the missing data column?

Comment: missing data is qoq - quarterly change..I dont know how that is calculated

Comment: A month's percentage change is relative to the prior month, the quarter's change is relative to the total sales during the prior quarter, and the year's change is relative to the total for the prior year. Correct?

Comment: Hi Tim, yes that is correct.

Answer (score 10):

This query works only in MSSQL2012, but it's plan and exec time are much better

```
SELECT
    year,
    month,
    sales,
    (sales - LAG(sales, 1) over (ORDER BY year, month)) / LAG(sales, 1) over (ORDER BY year, month)*100 AS mom,
    (sales - LAG(sales, 4) over (ORDER BY year, month)) / LAG(sales, 4) over (ORDER BY year, month)*100 AS qoq,
    (sales - LAG(sales, 12) over (ORDER BY year, month)) / LAG(sales, 12) over (ORDER BY year, month)*100 AS yoy
FROM @tab
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to use window function with [LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) here, but it works only in MSSQL2012. So I use row_number

```
declare @tab table (year int, month int, sales money)

insert into @tab values
(2010, 1, 80 ),(2010, 2, 61 ),(2010, 3, 81 ),
(2010, 4, 94 ),(2010, 5, 77 ),(2010, 6, 75 ),
(2010, 7, 58 ),(2010, 8, 74 ),(2010, 9, 98 ),
(2010, 10,  97 ),(2010, 11,  94 ),(2010, 12,  63 ),
(2011, 1, 61 ),(2011, 2, 79 ),(2011, 3, 84 ),
(2011, 4, 100),(2011, 5, 78 ),(2011, 6, 99 ),
(2011, 7, 78 ),(2011, 8, 63 ),(2011, 9, 66 ),
(2011, 10,  77 ),(2011, 11,  93 ),(2011, 12,  94 );

with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by year, month) rn,
        year,
        month,
        sales
    from @tab
)
select
    year,
    month,
    sales,
    round((sales-(select sales from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn-1))/(select sales from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn-1)*100.0,2) as mom,
    round((sales-(select sales from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn-4))/(select sales from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn-4)*100.0,2) as qoq,
    round((sales-(select sales from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn-12))/(select sales from cte where cte.rn=t1.rn-12)*100.0,2) as yoy
from cte as t1
```

Comment: could you please provide sample with usage of LAG too ?

Comment: @Alexander thanks this great..just a question for qoq, shouldn't the interval be 3 instead of 4? pls let me know